# Visual studio and string.format in new line parameters issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I override my ToString() method, My class contains many fields.
I can only have new line after the last string, and only place the variables in the next line.
Note - this is for visual purposes only, i dont not want a line seperate between prints.. only to see the full line in my 21" screen without scrolling.

This works:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}, IsAccessible = {1}, NetworkAddress = {2}, Manufacturer = {3}, Model = {4}, Firmware = {5}, Driver = {6}, MacAddress = {7}, Scenes count = {8}",
            base.ToString(), IsAccessible, NetworkAddress, Manufacturer, Model, Firmware, Driver, MacAddress, Scenes.Count);
    }
```

But this does **not work** (same code, only pressed enter after the 4th param):

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}, IsAccessible = {1}, NetworkAddress = {2}, Manufacturer = {3}, Model = {4},
        Firmware = {5}, Driver = {6}, MacAddress = {7}, Scenes count = {8}",
            base.ToString(), IsAccessible, NetworkAddress, Manufacturer, Model, Firmware, Driver, MacAddress, Scenes.Count);
    }
```

Comment: You cannot cut a string into two pieces

Comment: I do not wish to cut anything, i just want to continue writing the variables on a new line in the editor

Comment: Put @ after your Format Statement.
Then it will be interpreted as a string.
return String.Format(@"{0}, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` is a sequence of symbols in one row between quotes.

```
"one two" - is string.
"one
  two" - is an error.
```

you can create multiline strings in c# by concatenation of valid strings:

```
String s = "one" + Environment.NewLine + 
           " two";
```

or by adding `@` before the string

```
String s = @"one
             two";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a verbatim string, one that starts with an @ character:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format(@"{0}, IsAccessible = {1}, NetworkAddress = {2}, Manufacturer = {3}, Model = {4},
    Firmware = {5}, Driver = {6}, MacAddress = {7}, Scenes count = {8}",
        base.ToString(), IsAccessible, NetworkAddress, Manufacturer, Model, Firmware, Driver, MacAddress, Scenes.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of this is as follows:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format(
        "{0}, IsAccessible = {1}, NetworkAddress = {2}, Manufacturer = {3},"
        + " Model = {4}, Firmware = {5}, Driver = {6}, MacAddress = {7},"
        + " Scenes count = {8}",
        base.ToString(), IsAccessible, NetworkAddress, Manufacturer, Model, Firmware, Driver, MacAddress, Scenes.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string temp_var = @"{0}, IsAccessible = {1}, NetworkAddress = {2}, Manufacturer = {3}, Model = {4},
          Firmware = {5}, Driver = {6}, MacAddress = {7}, Scenes count = {8}";
temp_var = string.Format(base.ToString(), IsAccessible, NetworkAddress, Manufacturer, Model, Firmware, Driver, MacAddress, Scenes.Count);
return temp_var;
```

Just assigning the value to a string variable..